# How to access Android Emulator SD card Files on PC Window 10?

Tags: android, android-emulator, avd-manager, avdepthdata

using the Andriod emulator I have downloaded some files from the Internet on Google Chrome Browser. but I don't know where it's located on my PC, Kindly help me with that, here are the details of the emulator

- Name: Nexus_5_API_28
- CPU/ABI: Google X86_ARM Play Intel Atom (x86)
- Path: C:\Users\me.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_28.avd
- Target: google_ndk_playstore [Google X86_ARM Play] (API level 28)

Comment: You used the Chrome browser on the emulator?

Comment: From pc you have no access to files on emulator.

Comment: yes, I have used browser on emulator